# Can a picklist be dependent on 2 controlling picklists?

Tags: picklist, dependent-picklist

I have 3 fields. Category, sub-category and products. Sub-category is the dependent picklist of category and Products is the dependent picklist of Sub-category. But, not all Categories have Sub-categories so Products should also be a dependent picklist of Category. Is it possible for Products to have 2 controlling picklists? I did my research and it stated that this can be achieved only through VF page. Is there no possible way I can do this using customisation? Also, can someone please tell me how to do this using a VF page? I did read the other post on this topic but it was mentioned that this can be done using VF page. But the question is pretty old so is there any provision to do it now with the recent releases? Thanks!

Comment: I did read that and it was mentioned that this can be done using VF page. But the question is pretty old so is there any provision to do it now with the recent releases?

Comment: @User2529 have you tried to create two dependent picklist on object level?

Comment: Yup. Sub-catergory and Products are the dependent picklists in an object. Category is the controlling picklist on the same object. But as I have mentioned, Sub-category is dependent on category and Products is dependent on Sub-category but I am not able to create the dependency between Products and Category.